# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable fix in python card game

Tags: python, dictionary, debugging, error-handling

> TypeError: 'dict'
> object is not callable

Currently debugging a card game for a project and can't figure out how to fix this error. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 player_info = UI.get_player_information(MAX_PLAYERS)
 self.players = [player_classes(name) for name, typ in player_info]
```

Code for reference :

```
player_classes = {
'human': Player,
'simple': SmartAI,
'smart': SimpleAI,
}


def get_player_information(max_players):
    """get required information to set up a round"""

    # create players list
    player_info = []
    # how many human players?
    print("\nHow many human players [1-4]:")
    no_of_players = get_int_input(1, max_players)

    # for each player, get name
    for i in range(no_of_players):
        print(f"Please enter the name of player {i+1}:")
        player_info.append(('human', get_string_input()))

    ai_names = ['Angela', 'Bart', 'Charly', 'Dorothy']

    # how many AI players? ensure there are at least 2 players
    min_val = 1 if (len(player_info) == 0) else 0
    max_val = max_players - no_of_players
    print(f"\nHow many ai players [{min_val:d}-{max_val:d}]:")
    no_of_players = get_int_input(min_val, max_val)

    # randomly assign a simple or smart AI for each computer strategy
    for name in ai_names[:no_of_players]:
        if [True, False]:
            player_info.append(('simple', name))
        else:
            player_info.append(('smart', f"Smart {name}"))

    return player_info
```

Comment: You are trying `player_classes(name)`, but `player_classes` is a `dict` and not a `function`, so it is not callable. To index a `dict`, you need `player_classes[name]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `player_classes` as a `Callable` when the object is fact a `dict`, so you should access its elements by using the notation `dict[key]`.

You need to change your [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to

```py
self.players = [player_classes[player_type] for player_type, _ in player_info]
```

Note that you're creating your tuples with *type* as their first element and *name* as the second one.

Edit: forgot to change the variable name to something else (`type` is a Python function).